# How to update tensors matching dimensionwise vectors

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, torch

Let there be two 2D tensors, **A** (`m × c`) and **B** (`n × c`). Each row vector which belongs to **B** also belongs to **A** i.e. [image: r]. Additionally, row vectors in **A** are not unique i.e. **A** may have duplicate rows. However, row vectors in **B** are unique.

There another pair of tensors **P** (`m × f`) and **Q** (`n × f`). I am trying to do the following

```py
for i in range(B.shape[0]):
    rv = B[i, :]
    fv = Q[i, :]
    # P[<row indexes of A matching rv>, :] = fv
```

1. How to do this correctly?
2. Is it possible to get rid of the for loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following mask:

```py
for i in range(B.shape[0]):
    rv = B[i]
    fv = Q[i]
    mask = torch.where((A == rv).all(dim=1))[0]
    P[mask] = fv
```

Comment: Thanks. Any way to get rid of the for loop altogether?

Comment: @tachyon since you need to do a lookup in `A`  for every row in `B`, I can't think of any way that would avoid a for loop under the hood.